# Same e-mail after account deletion

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, privacy

If I delete my account, in order to anonimize my content, and then I'd like to register a new user, what's the policy and pitfalls when using the same e-mail account for it?

At first, is it allowed, and if it is, is it the risk that using the same e-mail could accidentally trigger the binding of the questions from 'old' account to the new one?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with registering using the email address you used in the older account; unless you want to have your old posts linked back to your new account (which you can ask for using "contact us"), they won't be linked.